# Execute tar command embeded in ssh command

Tags: python, ssh

I am trying to pull files from my webservers and would like to do this with python. I have the command below that willtar the files on the remote machine and pull them all back to the local machine. I do this manually with os.system and it prompts me for password. I enter it and it pulls the files. Is there anyway to detect a password prompt from os.system or if I use pexpect I detect the password prompt and enter it but the files do not get copied over. Any ideas?

```
ssh user1@myserver 'tar -cvf - -C  /usr/home/user1 .' | tar -xvf -

username = "user1"
servername = "myserver"
mypath = "/usr/home/user1"
import os
os.system("ssh user1@myserver 'tar -cvf - -C  /usr/home/user1 .' | tar -xvf -")
user1@myserver's password:
```

Comment: Why not use use scp?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure your ssh to connect without asking for password, see for example: http://web.archive.org/web/20160404025901/http://jaybyjayfresh.com/2009/02/04/logging-in-without-a-password-certificates-ssh/

Note, you can also use scp to copy the whole folder recursively:

```
scp -rp sourcedirectory user@dest:/path
```

`-r` means recursively
`-p` means preserve attributes

Comment: Unfortunately I can not use certs on these servers. Also I can use scp but the way scp works it opens closes a session for each file and takes much longer to copy over hundreds of files versus just copying a tar file over with one session in one command.